# Jenkins, Do not trigger "post build actions:trigger parameterized build" when built manually

Tags: jenkins

I have a job that, when complete, starts another job through post-build actions:trigger parametrized build. However at times, I wish to just run one specific job manually (not through the timer) without chaining off the rest of the jobs. How would I accomplish such a task.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't in your current setup.

You want the **[Flexible Publish Action](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin)** to make your post-build action conditional (probably based on parsing the console log for indication that the build is manual)